# Oracle procedure synonym operating over parent schema tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-schema, database-administration, synonym

Here is my scenario:

**Schema:** USER_1
**Package:** PKG_1
**Procedure:** PROC_1
**Table:** MY_TABLE

**Schema:** USER_2

So I have two schemas, **USER_2** has a synonym for almost every table in **USER_1**, it also has a synonym for **PKG_1.PROC_1**, which updates **MY_TABLE**. However, when using **USER_2** synonym for **PKG_1.PROC_1** the procedure update tables from **USER_1** instead of **USER_2**...

How could I operate over tables from the same schema that is executing synonym of a procedure in another schema?

Basically, what I expect is to actually see a change on **USER_2.MY_TABLE** but no change is done there...

I did this with **USER_2**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM MY_TABLE FOR USER_1.MY_TABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM PKG_1 FOR USER_1.PKG_1;
EXECUTE PKG_1;
```

I have no errors and even the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` logs are visible and correct when connected to **USER_2**. However, say **PKG_1.PROC_1** deletes a record from **MY_TABLE**, if I do:

```
SELECT RECORD FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Using USER_2, I can see the record was not deleted, but:

```
SELECT RECORD FROM USER_1.MY_TABLE;
```

Was deleted.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a package operate on objects in the schema of the caller you need to declare AUTHID CURRENT_USER on the package (aka invokers rights package).

The default is AUTHID DEFINER allowing the package to operate on objects available from the same schema as the package itself.